# Rule variables in ANTLR4

Tags: java, variables, migration, rules, antlr4

I'm trying to convert my grammar from v3 to v4 and having some trouble.

In v3 I have rules like this:

```
dataspec[DataLayout layout] returns [DataExtractor extractor]
    @init {
        DataExtractorBuilder builder = new DataExtractorBuilder(layout);
    }
    @after {
        extractor = builder.create();
    }
    : first=expr { builder.addAll(first); } (COMMA next=expr { builder.addAll(next); })* 
    ;

expr returns [List<ValueExtractor> ext]
    ...
```

However, with rules in v4 returning these custom context objects instead of what I explicitly told them to return, things are all messed up. What's the v4 way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple cases here:

- accessing passed-in variables (`layout`)
- accessing the current rule's return value (`extractor`)
- accessing local variables (`first`, `next`)

### Passed-in variables and current rule's return value

When accessing passed-in variables or the return value of the current rule you simply need to prefix the name given in the rule definition with `$`.

- `layout` becomes `$layout`
- `extractor` becomes `$extractor`

### Local Variables

Evidently what needs to be done is to reference the variables' member which is named according to the `returns` clause of the rule which returned the value.

For example, `first` is capturing the result from the `expr` rule, and `expr` names its return value `ext`, meaning that:

- `first` becomes `$first.ext`
- `next` becomes `$next.ext`

### When to Use the `$` form

Unlike in v3 where you could reference certain variables as regular java fields, using the `$` form is necessary in *all* cases, including in actions, in the `@init` and `@after` blocks, and when passing variables to other rules.

### Other traps

If you're capturing optional tokens in a local variable, you may run into null pointer exceptions now that you're referencing an attribute of that variable.

```
single_lname returns [String s]
    : p=LNAME_PREFIX? r=NAME { $p.text + toNameCase($r.text); }
;
```

You'll need to check whether `$p` is null, but most of the time this would result in a "missing attribute access" error. ANTLR4 makes a special exception so that you can check this, which *only* applies when used in an `if` condition (refactoring this to use the ternary operator, for example, will still result in the error).

```
single_lname returns [String s]
    : p=LNAME_PREFIX? r=NAME { 
        if ($p == null) {
            $s = toNameCase($r.text);
        } else {
            $s = $p.text + toNameCase($r.text);
        }
    }
;
```

### The updated rule

Putting it all together, the `dataspec` rule becomes:

```
dataspec[DataLayout layout] returns [DataExtractor extractor]
    @init {
        DataExtractorBuilder builder = new DataExtractorBuilder($layout);
    }
    @after {
        $extractor = builder.create();
    }
    : first=expr { builder.addAll($first.ext); }
        (COMMA next=expr { builder.addAll($next.ext); })* 
    ;
```

Comment: The rules for using `$` in V4 are nearly the same as the rules for V3. The reason grammars are breaking is an implementation detail in V3 resulted in the variable names being the same in the generated code as they appeared in the grammar, so failing to use the `$` worked *most of the time*. That implementation detail changed in V4.